# Submit or Refresh when select item in Html.Dropdownlist

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html.dropdownlistfor

I tried everything I know to refresh the page. 
this is my code:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Languages", "Select Language")
```

I tried:

```
 @Html.DropDownList("Languages", "Select Language", new { @onchange = "this.form.submit();" })
```

and without the @onchange (onchange), I tried to make javascript but it just wont add another parameter after my "select language" it always says "invalid arguments" so yeah, what else can i do to Select Item and then refresh the page?

**EDIT**

So to clarify, I have this dropdownlist

```
List<SelectListItem> Languages = new List<SelectListItem>();
Languages.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Hungarian", Value = "hu" });
Languages.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Hrvatski", Value = "hr" });
Languages.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Slovak", Value = "sk" });
Languages.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Bosanski", Value = "hr" });
Languages.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "English", Value = "en" });       
Languages.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Srpski", Value = "sr" });
```

in my controller, now when I click on `<button type="submit">next</button>`
it changes the language of the page by the value I selected

Comment: what exactly you need to do ?

Comment: after selecting item, to change the language of the page, that means a a postback, i have a Submit button, witch works perfectly. I select language in Dropdown box and press button = language changed. How to do that without the button.

Comment: button code `<button type="submit">next</button>`

Comment: what the button do in your page ?

Comment: "submit" just that, and the page changes language.

Comment: can you please update the question with full html and script ? so it will be more clear to understand.

Comment: What is you `DropDown` design code ? Just set `AutoPostBack` of `DropDown` to `true` to do `PostBack `after selecting an item.

Comment: @Aria Im using asp.net MVC, there is no design code, i use the HTML Helper.

Comment: @AlminIslamovic Aha right , there is no `AutoPostback` in MVC, would you like to write this by JQuery ?

Comment: @Aria aaand how would i achieve that? if I may ask

Comment: @AlminIslamovic Of course are you familiar with JQuery?

Comment: @Aria not too much :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71503/discussion-between-aria-and-almin-islamovic).

Answer (score 3):

There is no `AutoPostBack` in MVC you can achieve this by JQuery like this:

```
$("#Languages").change(function () {
    // You can refresh your page by code
    //  location.reload();
});
```

Or bind `change` to your `DropDown` like:

```
$("#Languages").bind("change",function(){
    // You can refresh your page by code
    //  location.reload();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

So what i did was `@Html.DropDownList("Languages", null, new { @onchange =  @"form.submit();"})`

and it worked.. so yeah thanks guys!